# How to use Angular Material DateRangePicker to enter only end date i.e. valid until

Tags: angular, angular-material, date-range

I develop an Angular 10 app where I have successfully implemented a Reactive Form which uses the [Angular Material DateRangePicker component](https://next.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-selection).

In this component, I can enter only a start date (valid from), a start date and an end date (valid between), but I can't figure out how to enter only an end date (valid until, i.e. no start date).

If there is no solution, I will use two datepicker components instead.

Comment: Wouldn't `mat-datepicker` suit your use case better then? As the dateRangePicker implies two dates (as per its name), I wouldn't expect to be able to pick only one.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, if there is no solution, I will use two datepicker components instead. But a range can be finite or infinite, with no lower bound or no upper bound. So I think this should be supported by the component. My use case is on validity period. I need the user to be able to enter from date X to date Y, until date X, or starting from date X.